# Which is best for 3D Rendering

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, unity-game-engine

In my ios app i have to do 3D Rendering for few Models (Machines), Which technology is best to do this ?,  either Unity or QuickTime VR with native frameworks (Can we play a QuickTime VR file in ios)
? please give me your thoughts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option is yours considering the 3D object that you would like to render on the screen and the manipulations that needs to be applied on it.

There are many frameworks available, a few examples are

**[Cocos3D](http://brenwill.com/cocos3d/)**

[**NinevehGL**](http://nineveh.gl)

[**SceneKit**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SceneKit_Framework/)

[**OpenGL ES**](https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/ios/documentation/OpenGLES/Reference/OpenGLES_Framework/index.html)

[**VES - KitwarePublic - VTK**](http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VES)